# How do I convert a dictionary that has nested dictionaries within it into a dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, nested

I recently did a sentiment analysis using Oracle's AI Language API in Python. I had the API iterate over 1300 Tweets and stored the output from the API in a list, where each element in the list corresponded with a single Tweet ID. I then created a dictionary, where the key was the Tweet ID and the value was the output from the API for that Tweet ID. I now have a massive dictionary with dictionaries nested within dictionaries and am not sure how to convert this to a dataframe in Pandas.

Here are the first few entries of the dictionary I am working with.

```
 {1292750633104289792: {
   "aspects": []
 },
 1275918779831238656: {
   "aspects": []
 },
 1293251961031204865: {
   "aspects": [
     {
       "length": 8,
       "offset": 51,
       "scores": {
         "Negative": 0.18023298680782318,
         "Neutral": 0.0,
         "Positive": 0.8197670578956604
       },
       "sentiment": "Positive",
       "text": "building"
     }
   ]
 },
 1293312774563606531: {
   "aspects": []
 },
 1293375754751881217: {
   "aspects": [
     {
       "length": 4,
       "offset": 5,
       "scores": {
         "Negative": 0.9987309575080872,
         "Neutral": 0.0012690634466707706,
         "Positive": 0.0
       },
       "sentiment": "Negative",
       "text": "poll"
     }
   ]
 }}
```

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can flatten your structure using a nested comprehension, and then pass the result to `pd.DataFrame`:

```
import pandas as pd
r = [{'tweet_id':a, 
       'length':i['length'],
        'offset':i['offset'],
        **{f'score_{j}':k for j, k in i['scores'].items()},
        'sentiment':i['sentiment'],
        'text':i['text'],
     } 
     for a, b in data.items() for i in (b['aspects'] if isinstance(b, dict) else b.aspects)]

df = pd.DataFrame(r)
```

Output:

```
              tweet_id  length  offset  score_Negative  score_Neutral  score_Positive sentiment      text
0  1293251961031204865       8      51        0.180233       0.000000        0.819767  Positive  building
1  1293375754751881217       4       5        0.998731       0.001269        0.000000  Negative      poll
```

Comment: I just tried this using my original dictionary, and it did not work for some reason, not sure why. I am getting this error `TypeError: 'DetectLanguageSentimentsResult' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: @Jared That is probably because you full data has `aspects` values that are not standard types. Can you post a larger sample of your data?

Comment: Here is a [link](https://github.com/jaredbach/HerzlBot/blob/main/sentiment.txt) to the dictionary I am using, I saved it as text file and uploaded it to GitHub, so it is easier to view.

Comment: @Jared In your code, is the `scores` key pointing to a dictionary, or `DetectLanguageSentimentsResult`? Based on the error, I think it is the latter. If so, then instead of `{f'score_{j}':k for j, k in i['scores'].items()}`, you can do `{'score_Negative':i['scores'].negative, ....}` or something to that effect, accessing the score values via attribute.

Comment: I am honestly not too sure, I have no idea where this error is coming from. Let me try that. How would the rest of the code look after your `...` ? Something like this? `{'score_Negative':i['scores'].negative, 'score_Positive':i['scores'].positive, 'score_Neutral':i['score'].netral}`

Comment: Also what do the two `**` at the beginning of that line of code mean?

Comment: I just tried this `**{'score_Negative':i['scores'].negative, 'score_Positive':i['scores'].positive, 'score_Neutral':i['score'].neutral},` and I got the same error

Comment: Not sure if [this](https://oracle-cloud-infrastructure-python-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/ai_language/models/oci.ai_language.models.DetectDominantLanguageResult.html) helps but that is the API I used.

Comment: @Jared Can you print what the first full `aspects` value looks like in your console? It might be the case that all the objects in the list under `aspects` are, in fact instances of `DetectLanguageSentimentsResult`.

Comment: @Jared You can do something like `type(data[1293251961031204865]['aspects'][0])`

Comment: So I just checked the data type and interestingly enough, yet again, received the same error. So weird. `TypeError: 'DetectLanguageSentimentsResult' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: @Jared What is the result of `type(data[1293251961031204865])`?

Comment: `oci.ai_language.models.detect_language_sentiments_result.DetectLanguageSentimentsResult`

Comment: @Jared What is the result of `data[1293251961031204865].aspects`?

Comment: `[{
   "length": 8,
   "offset": 51,
   "scores": {
     "Negative": 0.18023298680782318,
     "Neutral": 0.0,
     "Positive": 0.8197670578956604
   },
   "sentiment": "Positive",
   "text": "building"
 }]`

Comment: @Jared Please see my recent edit.

Comment: Now am getting this error `TypeError: 'SentimentAspect' object is not subscriptable` at this line `----> 3        'length':i['length']`

Comment: Definitely seem on to something.

Comment: @Jared Try `i.length`, `i.offset`, etc

Comment: Okay cool...Now am getting this error, haha `'dict' object has no attribute 'aspects'` in the last line `for a, b in data.items() for i in b.aspects]`

Comment: @Jared It looks like you might have a mixture of `DetectLanguageSentimentsResult` and dictionaries in your data. To check this, you can replace  `b.aspects` with `b['aspects'] if isinstance(b, dict) else b.aspects`

Comment: It says its an invalid syntax `for a, b in data.items() for i in b['aspects'] if isinstance(b, dict) else b.aspects]` Am I writing this incorrectly?

Comment: @Jared you can surround the condition in parenthesis: `for a, b in data.items() for i in (b['aspects'] if isinstance(b, dict) else b.aspects)`

Comment: It worked thank you so much! I will post the final answer!

Comment: @Jared I updated my post to include that change.

Comment: How does this solution handle the empty `"aspects": [ ]` Does it just not include these Tweet IDs in the dataframe? Or are they blank?

Comment: @Jared They are not included, as iterating over `[]` does not produce anything

Comment: Hmmm OK! Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @Jared Glad to help!